# How do I add up a number to a properties in my object?

Tags: javascript, function, object, addition

I have an object like this:

```
var statistics = {
    won: 0,
    tie: 0,
    lost: 0
};
```

I have a function that adds 1 to `won`:

```
var plus1 = function() {
    return statistics.won++;
}
```

I call that function within an if/else statement like this:

```
plus1();
```

But it doesn't work. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Is `statistics` visible at the point you are trying to access it? Doesn't your browser's console show any errors?

Comment: "It doesnt work" - why? Is there an error?

Comment: no errors in the browser's console no..

Comment: So, what's happening, then? What doesn't work?

Comment: Provide full code, cause I don't understand where plus1 fucntion stored.

Comment: `return ++statistics.won;`?

Comment: @AstroCB it makes sense...just the wrong use of ++

Comment: @user3124133: once again: You say it _"Doesn't work"_. What ___exactly___ do you mean? What is happening, and what do you need to happen?

Comment: When I push a button the parameters in a function change which will declare which if statement would come out. I now have in all my if statements an 'plus1();' So eventually what should happen: is that every time I push the button the parameter in the object should add one up.

Comment: Looking at [your site](http://ivoklerk.com/rpslspro), as @J.Beyer mentioned, the problem isn't in the code in your question. You just need to update the score display in each call of `plus1`;

Answer (score 4):

It's probably that x++ returns x instead of x+1.
You are looking for

```
var plus1 = function() {
    return ++statistics.won;
}
```

Comment: Well @Andy, you should have made it an answer and not a comment.

Comment: to be fair: I didn't see your comment before.

Comment: unfortunately that still doesn't work. The problem is somewhere else. My site is: ivoklerk.com/rpslspro

Comment: maybe try to call wins() after plus1().

Comment: @J.Beyer: Yea, that's the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code I don't really see any reason why you would return your result.

I would rewrite the function to simply be

```
function plus1() {
  statistics.won++;
}
```

When it comes to having it update, I can't see any were in your code where you actually update the html. After you've run plus1(). If I run console.log(statistics) in my Console I can see that statistic.won goes up whenever I win.

As already mentioned in the comment above, if you run wins() after you've run plus1() it will all work.

Comment: wins(); is under plus1(); in my code.. How do I update the html?

Comment: whenever you've run plus1(); you need to run wins() again. So change `plus1();` into `plus1(); wins();`

Comment: Or just add `wins();` to the `plus1` function.

Comment: If you feel like the question have been answered you might want to mark it as answered.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to to way pre/post incrementation works in JavaScript:

```
var one = 1;
var two = 1;

// increment `one` FIRST and THEN assign it to `three`.
var three = ++one; 

// assign `two` to `four`, THEN increment it
var four = two++;
```

So in your code, you're assigning the value of `statistics.won` to the `return` value first and then incrementing it. [You can see the difference in how they work here](http://jsfiddle.net/D3ew6/3/).

So, as I mentioned in the comments, `return ++statistics.won;` is the solution you need.